# what is the value of rel attribute if type is text/html in link tag and html file tend to add content in including page

Tags: php, html, css

i want to include html file in another page by using include tag , but i did not  know what the value of rel attribute is ?

this is my code : ( this file has extension .php )

```
<html>
<head>
    <link href="a.html" type="text/html" rel="" > <!--what the value of rel attr ? -->
</head>
<body>
<?php
/*php code*/
?>
</body>
</html>
```

a.html contains tags in `body` and `head` sections , that appear in the including page header

Comment: Your content should not appear in the `head` tag. If your `a.html` contains only tags that can go in the `head` you can use php to write it `echo file_get_contents("a.html");`

Comment: @Psioniax my [a.html] contains tags in [body] and [head] also

Comment: Why are you exactly including it instead of manually writing the contents to the php file?

Comment: @Psioniax  because i want a.html include in multiple php files , so i need to be external file.

Comment: Then split in in 2 files, one of which contains `head`-allowed tags, but not the `head` tag itself. (e.g. `<script...><link...><title>Your title</title>`). Same with your body.

Comment: @Psioniax   why i must do this split ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108357/discussion-between-safana-and-psioniax).